# Error when trying to write to database Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am still learning Python via Django and have been doing most of my methods in views. I have been told that it is better practice to put them in my models under a Manager. I have the following code grabbing the product info and I believe the id to fill my model. but its throwing an error. Any help would be great.

Updated error after moving stuff in to model. Now it does't regonize request.session

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\myenvirnoments\djangoENv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\blackbelttest ver 1\blackbelttest\apps\blackbeltapp\views.py" in create
  43.   viewsResponse = Myblackbelt.objects.add_product(request.POST)

File "C:\Users\dbhol\Desktop\blackbelttest ver 1\blackbelttest\apps\blackbeltapp\models.py" in add_product
  9.        secreteid= User.objects.get(id=request.session['loguser_id'])

Exception Type: NameError at /blackbelt/create
Exception Value: global name 'request' is not defined
    Html matters

     <form class="" action="{% url 'blackbelt:create' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p>Product: <input type="text" name="product" value=""></p>
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Create">
            </form>


    view.py that matters

    def create(request):
    viewsResponse = Myblackbelt.objects.add_product(request.POST)


    return redirect ('blackbelt:index')

    Models in full

   from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from ..logReg.models import User

class ProductManager(models.Manager):

    def add_product(self, postData):
        print 'dog here'
        secreteid= User.objects.get(id=request.session['loguser_id'])
        Myblackbelt = self.create(product = postData['product'], creator=secreteid)




class Myblackbelt(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    loguser = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='loguser')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')


    objects = ProductManager()
```

Comment: The problem is that there's no `product` key on your POST dict. In your case rather than using custom managers you should check [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/)

Comment: Also, how do you pass `secreteid` to the `creator` field?

Comment: For school they want u to make the forms and want us to do our own login  and nik def add_product(self, postData):
  print 'dog here'
  secreteid= User.objects.get(id=request.session['loguser_id'])
  Myblackbelt = self.create(product = postData['product'], creator=secreteid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not well structure and it'll break soon. However, to overcome the `MultiValueDictKeyError` error write these:

```
# views.py

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        viewsResponse = Myblackbelt.objects.add_product(request.POST)
        secreteid= User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])

    return redirect ('blackbelt:index')


class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def add_product(self, postData):
        # always set a default value if dict key is not found
        # of course you must (also) check if postData is of type dict
        product = postData.get('product', None)
        creator_id = postData.get('loguser_id', None)
        if product is not None and creator_id is not None:
            creator = User.objects.get(id=creator_id)
            Myblackbelt = self.create(product=product, creator=creator)
        print 'dog here'
```

Comment: nik I would like to chat with you when you have time